# How to add a external run configuration programmatically (or from XML)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to add a "run configuration" in an Eclipse RCP application, under the "external tool configuration" dialog, **so that the user can run an external executable already configured by me** (with command line parameter ecc..).

How to do that? I have googled for it but found nothing: it can be done by creatinfg a new custom tab group in the dialog. But I want to reuse the program tab group which is already defined:

[image]

I would like my configuration to appear under that "program" tag group. Is that even possible??
Thank you!!

Comment: This is all part of the "Launch Configuration" code, which is rather complex. There is a whole section in the Eclipse Help on this - "Platform Plug-in Developer Guide > Programmer's Guide > Program debug and launch support"

Comment: Ok I've read it.. And yes it's complex.. Can you give me an hint? I can't seem to find the information I need in that help..

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't used these APIs for a very long time. It is going to be some sort of `ILaunchConfiguration`. Maybe look at the xxx.launch file for an existing tool.

Comment: Yes the launch configuration is

org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ProgramLaunchConfigurationType

defined in org.eclipse.debug.core.externatools plugin.

But how to add my own tool I still don't know.
I ended up doing my own launch configuration tab group for my custom program. It makes also more sens to my application..